# pre-login handshake SQL server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am getting the following error.

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an
>   error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider
>   The specified network name is no longer available) ((Microsoft SQL
>   Server, Error: 64).

Comment: Check if the SQL services are stopped .Restart it .

Comment: MsSQLSERVER service is running. But SQL server Agent is not running. When trying to start it it gives me an error - "the request failed or the service didn't respond in a timely fashion".  For running SQL server, Agent service should be running?